# C++ - What does this double pointer/array structure really mean? I have trouble picturing it

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, data-structures

This is within C++ code

```
YInterface ** Y_list;

int numberofYInterfaces;
```

then

```
numberofYInterfaces=1;

Y_list = new YInterface *[numberofYInterfaces];        //What ??????
```

I have a very hard time picturing the structure of Y_list? And then imagine my confusion when and if the numberofYInterfaces becomes more than one, even 2?

**OOPS** sorry and I forgot to write this below statement:

```
Y_list[i]= new AnotherClass();
```

//later addition to my orginal question .  Thanks for the headsup Eric Fortin. 
Note: AnotherClass is inherited from YInterface.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: It's difficult(though possible) to explain without knowing what YInterface actually does

Comment: Better (imho) asterisk placement would help a lot in understanding: `Y_list = new YInterface* [numberofYInterfaces];`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you declare `Y_list`, you get a single variable with an unspecified value in it:

```
Y_list
+-------+
|       |
+-------+
```

When you assign it with `new[]`, it points to whatever `new[]` allocated, which in this case is an array of pointers:

```
Y_list         array
+-------+     +-------+
|   o---+---->|       |
+-------+     +-------+
              |       |
              +-------+
              |       |
              +-------+
              |       |
              +-------+
              |       |
              +-------+
```

At that point, you don't yet have any `YInterface` objects. You just have space allocated to hold *pointers* to them, should they ever exist.

Finally, you assign a value to one of the elements `Y_list[i] = new AnotherClass`. That's when a `YInterface` descendant exists, but you only have one so far. Run that code in a loop and you'll get multiple instances. But you still just have one array, and one pointer to that array.

```
Y_list         array         AnotherClass
+-------+     +-------+     +-------+
|   o---+---->|   o---+---->|       |
+-------+     +-------+     |       |
              |       |     |       |
              +-------+     |       |
              |       |     |       |
              +-------+     +-------+
              |       |
              +-------+
              |       |
              +-------+
```

To free all this, remember to have one `delete` statement for each `new` statement you had, and one `delete[]` for each `new[]`:

```
delete Y_list[i];

delete[] Y_list;
```

Comment: +1 for nice graphics :) It always helps when dealing with pointers and dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy : When you say "When you assign it with new[], it points to whatever new[] allocated, which in this case is an array of pointers:

Comment: " in this case it does not say new[] it says new *[]. The astrik throws me??  Can you please explain that too.  Thanks

Comment: @User, when you use `new`, the thing following `new` is the name of the type you're allocating. If you're allocating an array of that type, then the type is followed by brackets. The type in this case is *pointer-to-YInterface*, or `YInterface*`. The space between the base type name and the asterisk  doesn't matter to the compiler. If I were writing this code, I'd write `new YInterface* [...]`. There's no such thing as `*[]`. The asterisk goes with the type name before it, not the brackets after it.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: So, in your graphics am I correct that you have assumed that numberofYInterfaces is actually 5? I would highly appreciate your reply. You have been extremely helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't really count as I was drawing it, but yes, the array's length is five in my example. I didn't notice that your code used just one. The length doesn't really matter. When you draw your own diagrams, make them as long or as short as you need.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy Well, thank you very much. Overall an awesome explanation. You have a gift for it. Thanks.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, If everything else stayed the same, what would have happened if Y_list was only declared as YInterface * Y_list?

Comment: @User, if `Y_list` were declared as a `YInterface*, then your code would no longer compile. The expression `new YInterface*[...]` has type `YInterface**`, and you're not allowed to assign that to something of type `YInterface*`.

Answer (score 2):

It means it's a dynamically allocated array of pointers on YInterface. Then suppose method blah is part of YInterface, you could access it through the array like:

```
Y_list[0]->blah();
```

Concerning your edit. Every item in the array is a pointer on YInterface so to actually have something pointed to, you need to allocate it which you do with `new` operator. So doing `Y_list[i] = new AnotherClass()` does allocate an AnotherClass object and store a pointer on this object in the array at index i.

Keep in mind though that AnotherClass needs to inherit YInterface for this to work.

Comment: Thank you for  your answer. It was very helpful to lead me closer to the resolution. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Y_list points to a chunk of memory which is an array of pointers to YInterface objects -- each pointer is sizeof (YInterface *), so this chunk of memory (after the call to new) is of size numberOfYInterfaces * sizeof (YInterface *).

So Y_list is just a normal dynamically allocated array, with numberOfYInterfaces elements, each of which is itself a pointer to a YInterface object.

Answer (score 0):

in c++ array are pointers , that is the memory address of first element of array is the name of array , so now what you have is array of pointers , hence **

Comment: Arrays are **not** pointers, see my [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/) on arrays.